# Not Working in Other Pc's

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory

Hi i have the following code which works fine in my machine but when i give my install set in other machines  application is been crashed and giving me error .
  And the functionality i am trying to achive is I am backing schema and data for few tables into an output folder and if the user checks  the Schema_checkbox then the backup file should delete the lines till schema and just leave the data bit . So finally it will contain data but not schema . This bit is working fine on my machine but not in support desk who installed my exe.

My code :

```
if (Schema_checkbox.Checked)
{
  DisplayMainWindow("Schema not required selected");
  Logger.Log("Schema not required selected " + DateTime.Now);
  FileHelper.CopyFileContent(outputFileName);
  DisplayMainWindow(" Only table data is backup excluding schema");
  Logger.Log(" Only table data is backup excluding schema" + DateTime.Now);
}

public void CopyFileContent(string filePath)
{
  try
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string newText = null;
    using (StreamReader tsr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
       do
       {
         string textLine = tsr.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
         {
           if (textLine.StartsWith("INSERT INTO"))
           {
              newText += textLine + Environment.NewLine;
           }
          }
        }
        while (tsr.Peek() != -1);
        tsr.Close();
     }
     File.WriteAllText(filePath, newText);
    }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logger.Log("Exception" + ex);
    MessageBox.Show("Error Occured" + ex);
  }
}
```

Error Message :

> 27/09/2011 14:46:34  Started backing Table data
>   27/09/2011 14:46:54  Exception is : System.OutOfMemoryException:
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32
>   startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
>   at System.Text.StringBuilder.GetNewString(String currentString, Int32
>   requiredLength)   at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(String value)
>   at ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting.Generator.GenerateTableContent(String tableName,
>   Boolean saveImageFiles)
>   at ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting.Generator.GenerateTableData(String tableName,
>   Boolean saveImageFiles)
>   at ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting.Generator.GenerateTableScript(String tableName,
>   String outputFolder, Boolean isBackupReq)
>   at ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting.Generator.GenerateSchemaGraph(String
>   connectionString, List`1 tables, String outputFolderPath, Boolean
>   isDataBackupReq)
>   at SqlDatabaseDataExport.MainForm.BackupScriptLocation()

Comment: "System.OutOfMemoryException" - Your application is using too much memory. Reduce memory usage or install the program on a less "outdated" computer.

Comment: The exception does not occur in the code you included. `CopyFileContent` does not appear anywhere in the stack trace.

Comment: @hungrymind It is used in the 3rd party dll

Comment: Please put some more effort in when asking questions - your code is badly formatted, what exactly is "itthe"?  Your call stack doesn't seem to match the code given anyway and you haven't told us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  You can't even be bothered to properly capitalise your I's.

Comment: @Justin I am trying to read a file which consists of both sql data and schema and if the checkboc is selected the file should have only data deleting the schema thata the original functionality i am trying to achive and sorry about the spelling mistake as i got mistaken while typing fast

Comment: @ShaliniPavan You should edit your question with additional detail - detail posted in comments is more difficult to read and tends to go un-noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you try to open is very big, you can reach a limit where your system will run low in memory. I suggest you that you open the stream to read the file and then and other stream to write into the other file with a buffer (use StringBuilder). This way, your `newText` won't reach a very high level of memory because you will control the size with the StringBuilder. Also, it's always better when concatenate a lot of string to use a StringBuilder instead of String because the String use more memory. At the end of my suggestion, you just need to delete the original file and rename the output file with the name of the first file. That's it.

Comment: Good advice, but for a start he could use the stack trace to find where the exception is actually being thrown.

Comment: @Daok Is it possible to send me some code deleting the original file and rename the output file

Comment: System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\From.txt", @"C:\TO.txt");//Rename

Comment: File.Delete(fileToDelete);//Delete